# Singleton Service in weblogic cluster is registering but not invoking activate method

Tags: weblogic, ejb-3.1

I am implementing a singleton service in a weblogic 12.2.1.2 with EBJ 3.1 in a maven multimodule EAR project.

My singleton service is registering in the cluster.

This is the log from the node where is registered:

```
<BEA-000189> <The Singleton Service Appscoped_Singleton_Service is now active on this server.>
```

And this is from other node:

```
<BEA-003130> <Appscoped_Singleton_Service successfully activated on server iss3.>
```

The singleton service is implementing the interface **weblogic.cluster.singleton.SingletonService** but the methods **activate** and **deactivate** is not invoked when the nodes starts or shutdown.

I was reading something about versioned EARs and MANIFEST files but not understood this.

I need some help to make methods **activate** and **deactivate** be invoked.

This is my class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.test.MyTimerLocal;
import weblogic.cluster.singleton.SingletonService;

public class MySingletonServiceClass implements SingletonService, Serializable, MySingletonServiceInterface {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3966807367110330202L;

    private static final String jndiName = "MySingletonServiceClass";

    private int myValue;

    @Inject
    private MyTimerLocal myTimer;

    @Override
    public int getMyValue() {

        return this.myValue;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setMyValue(final int myValue) {

        this.myValue = myValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void activate() {

        System.out.println("activate triggered");
        Context ic = null;
        try {
            ic = new InitialContext();
            ic.bind(MySingletonServiceClass.jndiName, this);

            System.out.println("Object now bound in JNDI at " + MySingletonServiceClass.jndiName);

            this.myValue = 5;

            final String msg = "###################### MySingletonServiceClass.activate():: Fechamento agendado para " + this.myTimer.agendaExecucao() + " ###############";
            System.out.println(msg);
        } catch (final NamingException e) {
            this.myValue = -1;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ic != null) {
                    ic.close();
                }
            } catch (final NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deactivate() {

        System.out.println("deactivate triggered");
        Context ic = null;
        try {
            ic = new InitialContext();
            ic.unbind(MySingletonServiceClass.jndiName);
            System.out.println("Context unbound successfully");
        } catch (final NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why do you think the methods are not invoked? Because of lack of outputs in logs?

Comment: I got this working now with this in my **src\main\application\META-INF\weblogic-application.xml**

`<wls:singleton-service>
        <wls:class-name>com.test.MySingletonServiceClass</wls:class-name>
        <wls:name>Appscoped_Singleton_Service</wls:name>
    </wls:singleton-service>`

Answer (score 0):

I got this working now with this in my **src\main\application\META-INF\weblogic-application.xml**

```
<wls:singleton-service>
    <wls:class-name>com.test.MySingletonServiceClass</wls:class-name>
    <wls:name>Appscoped_Singleton_Service</wls:name>
</wls:singleton-service>
```